# "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response

Tags: node.js, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working on a chat bot that asks the user to describe their day by asking some questions and also if you type help it will check on the users stress depression and happiness scale by asking some questions and by giving a score based on the users reply but when I test in the simulator and my phone after asking like 2 or 3 questions the stops responding and this error shows up:

> "Failed to parse Dialog-flow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: and intentId:." (I have removed intent and agentid here)

```js
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function handleStress(agent) {
        let id = agent.context.get('greet-followup').parameters.id;
        let firstAns = agent.context.get('firstquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let secondAns = agent.context.get('secondquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let thirdAns = agent.context.get('thirdquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let fourthAns = agent.context.get('fourthquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let fifthAns = agent.context.get('fifthquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let finalcount = (firstAns + secondAns + thirdAns + fourthAns + fifthAns) * 2;
        if (finalcount > 0 && finalcount <= 10) {
            agent.add('Your stress levels are normal. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 10 && finalcount <= 14) {
            agent.add('Your stress levels are mild. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 14 && finalcount <= 21) {
            agent.add('Your stress levels are moderate. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 21 && finalcount <= 29) {
            agent.add('Your stress levels are severe. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 29) {
            agent.add('Your stress levels are extremely severe. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        let ref = admin.app().database().ref('/'+id+'/'+getDate());
        let obj = {
          stressScore:finalcount
        };
        return ref.update(obj);
    }

    function handleDepression(agent) {
        let id = agent.context.get('greet-followup').parameters.id;
        let firstAns = agent.context.get('depressionfirstquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let secondAns = agent.context.get('depressionsecondquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let thirdAns = agent.context.get('depressionthirdquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let fourthAns = agent.context.get('depressionfourthquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let fifthAns = agent.context.get('depressionfifthquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let sixthAns = agent.context.get('depressionsixthquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let finalcount = (firstAns + secondAns + thirdAns + fourthAns + fifthAns + sixthAns) * 2;
        if (finalcount > 0 && finalcount <= 14) {
            agent.add('Your depression levels are normal. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 14 && finalcount <= 18) {
            agent.add('Your depression levels are mild. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 18 && finalcount <= 25) {
            agent.add('Your depression levels are moderate. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 25 && finalcount <= 33) {
            agent.add('Your depression levels are severe. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 33) {
            agent.add('Your depression levels are extremely severe. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        let ref = admin.app().database().ref('/'+id+'/'+getDate());
        let obj = {
          depressionScore:finalcount
        };
        return ref.update(obj);
    }

    function handleHappiness(agent) {
        let id = agent.context.get('greet-followup').parameters.id;
        let firstAns = agent.context.get('happinessfirstquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let secondAns = agent.context.get('happinesssecondquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let thirdAns = agent.context.get('happinessthirdquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let fourthAns = agent.context.get('happinessfourthquestion-followup').parameters.number;
        let finalcount = (firstAns + secondAns + thirdAns + fourthAns) * 2;
        console.log(finalcount);
        if (finalcount > 0 && finalcount <= 10) {
            agent.add('Your happiness levels are low. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 10 && finalcount <= 14) {
            agent.add('Your happiness levels are normal. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 14 && finalcount <= 21) {
            agent.add('Your happiness levels are moderate. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 21 && finalcount <= 29) {
            agent.add('Your happiness levels are high. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        if (finalcount > 29) {
            agent.add('Your happiness levels are extremely high. Is that all? you can type help for getting other options.');
        }
        let ref = admin.app().database().ref('/'+id+'/'+getDate());
        let obj = {
          happinessScore:finalcount
        };
        return ref.update(obj);
    }

    function userDay(agent){
        let sentiment = request.body.queryResult.sentimentAnalysisResult.queryTextSentiment.score;
        let id = agent.context.get('greet-followup').parameters.id;
        let ref = admin.app().database().ref('/'+id+'/'+getDate());
        let obj = {
          stressScore:0,
          depressionScore:0,
          happinessScore:0,
          sentimentScore:(sentiment*100)
        };
        ref.set(obj);
        agent.add('Great, Type help to see what all I can do.');
    }
    function getDate() {
      var d = new Date(),
          month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
          day = '' + d.getDate(),
          year = d.getFullYear(),
          hour = d.getHours()+':00:00';
      if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
      if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
      if (hour.length < 8) hour = '0' + hour;
      return [year, month, day, hour].join('-');
    }

    function userStats(agent){
        let id = agent.context.get('greet-followup').parameters.id;
        let ref = admin.app().database().ref('/'+id+'/');
        return ref.limitToLast(1).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            const stress=data.child('stressScore').val();
            const depression=data.child('depressionScore').val();
            const anxiety=data.child('happinessScore').val();
            const sentiment=data.child('sentimentScore').val();
            agent.add('Hi your stats for today are:\nStress: '+stress+'\nDepression: '+depression+'\nHappiness: '+anxiety+'\nEmotional: '+sentiment);
          });
        });
    }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Fifth-Question', handleStress);
    intentMap.set('Depression-Fifth-Question', handleDepression);
    intentMap.set('Happiness-Fourth-Question', handleHappiness);
    intentMap.set('Day first question', userDay);
    intentMap.set('stats', userStats);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: You need to look at using Promises and how to handle asynchronous code flows.

Comment: it would really help if you could help me out mate!! :/